# "Housewife" vs "Homemaker"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

Imagine someone asks a woman about their job:

> What's your job ma'am?

She has no job and works as a mother and keeps home. What is the common term to such a profession in modern AmE?

She can say:

> a - I'm a **housewife**.
>
> b - I'm a **homemaker**.

As far as I know, the word housewife is [not](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-Homemaker-and-a-Housewife) very pleasant to be heard by a woman. Instead they prefer to be called "homemaker". Hence, 'b' should work better here. Do you confirm it?
If not, what a native would call such a woman?

Comment: If kids are involved the term "stay-at-home Mom" can be used.

Comment: "Housewife vs homemaker" question was answered and closed [here on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119527/housewife-vs-homemaker).

Answer (score 3):

I'm under the impression that *homemaker* has been gaining traction in recent decades, partly because some find *housewife* to be a mildly offensive term. (That viewpoint is not universally held; you can probably also find some who are offended by the fact that others find the word offensive.)

When the word *housewife* was coming out of vogue in some circles, a common refrain was: [*Don't call me a housewife – I'm not married to my house!*](https://www.google.com/search?q=housewife%20%22I%27m%20not%20married%20to%20my%20house%22)

In any case, this subject has been addressed in blogs and other online forums; I thought [this blog](http://littlejennywren.blogspot.com/2007/07/great-debate.html) and [this discussion on StraightDope](https://web.archive.org/web/20180708162814/boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-415903.html) gave some viewpoints that might be of interest to the learner.

TL;DR: I think *homemaker* is probably the "safer" alternative nowadays, but it's good to remember that not every stay-at-home mom abhors the term *housewife*.

Comment: One advantage of homemaker mentioned in the StraightDope discussion is that while it almost always means a woman, there's no reason it couldn't also mean a man who takes care of the home, while housewife is undeniably feminine.

Comment: "Housewife" is still vastly more common than "homemaker": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=housewife%2Chomemaker%2Cstay-at-home&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chousewife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chomemaker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstay%20-%20at%20-%20home%3B%2Cc0 .  Furthermore, "homemaker" peaked around 1980 and has been declining in usage since then.  "Stay-at-home" is very uncommon, comparatively.

Comment: @JonathanCast - An Ngram only shows that one word is more common than another in **written works**. If you peruse the hits, you'll see Google is finding the word _housewife_ in books like the reprint of [_The American Frugal Housewife_](https://books.google.com/books?id=L9VlWD-dZqsC) (first published in 1829), or [_The Virginia Housewife_](https://books.google.com/books?id=-KRGDwAAQBAJ). On the other hand, in the past ten seasons of the TV game show _Jeopardy!_, there were twenty contestants who chose to be introduced as homemakers, while only five were introduced as a housewife.